# How to delete old images uploaded via FAPI

Tags: 7, files

Consider the following bit of code in my custom module... It allows a user to upload an image, saves the fid as a variable, and in a custom submit function, it makes sure that the file in the file_managed table is saved permanently.

This all works great, but when my users are uploading a file, then saving, then removing that old file and uploading another and saving, all of these files are left in the file_managed table, with a status of 1.

```
function MYMODULE_admin() {
  $form = array();
  $form['style']['business_logo_fid'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Business Logo'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('Upload a logo for your business in one of the following formats: jpg png jpeg.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('business_logo_fid', ''),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg png jpeg'),
    ),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
  );

  $form = system_settings_form($form);
  $form['#submit'][] = 'after_save_ui';
  return $form;
}

function after_save_ui($form, &$form_state) {

    $business_logo_fid = variable_get('business_logo_fid');
    if ($business_logo_fid) {
        $business_logo = file_load($business_logo_fid);
        $business_logo->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
        file_save($business_logo);
    }

}
```

How do i mark these old images as unused after a new one has been saved in its place? Is there something I can do to get the fid from the old file and mark its status as 0 before the new one gets saved? or is this something that Drupal handles already for me?

Answer (score 0):

Its always the way! You spend an hour fussing over it, but when you actually write the question down, you think of it in a different way!

Its a bit long winded, but my complete example is this...

```
 function MYMODULE_admin() {
      $form = array();
      $form['style']['business_logo_fid'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Business Logo'),
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#description' => t('Upload a logo for your business in one of the following formats: jpg png jpeg.'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('business_logo_fid', ''),
        '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg png jpeg'),
        ),
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
      );

      $form = system_settings_form($form);
      $form['#submit'][] = 'after_save_ui';
      return $form;
    }

    function after_save_ui($form, &$form_state) {

        // Save the Business Logo Permenantly.
if (isset($form_state['values']['business_logo_fid'])) {
        $new_logo_id = $form_state['values']['business_logo_fid'];
        $old_logo_id = $form_state['complete form']['style']['business_logo_fid']['#default_value'];
          if (($old_logo_id != 0) && ($new_logo_id != $old_logo_id)){
            $business_logo_file = file_load($old_logo_id);
            if (!empty($business_logo_file)) {
              file_usage_delete($business_logo_file, 'webfroth_booking_ui', 'business', $business_logo_id);
              file_delete($business_logo_file, TRUE);
              drupal_set_message(t('Old Logo Removed.'));
            }
          }
          if (($new_logo_id != 0) && ($new_logo_id != $old_logo_id)){
            $current_business_logo = file_load($new_logo_id);
            if (!empty($current_business_logo->fid)) {
              $business_logo_file_id = $current_business_logo->fid;
              variable_set('business_logo_fid', $business_logo_file_id);
              file_usage_add($current_business_logo, 'webfroth_booking_ui', 'business', $business_logo_file_id);
              $current_business_logo->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
              file_save($current_business_logo);
              drupal_set_message("New Logo Uploaded Successfully.");
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

This works great, but it CANT be the standard way to handle this everytime I want to use an image field in a custom module surely? Seems like a massive hassle!